# Filtering by dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

I'm trying to create a filtered sheet (tab) inside Google Sheets by the end of the year. I already have it set up to filter by Department, but I can't get it to filter by year.

I have a DataSheet tab where people can go in and put their raw data for Departments, Project Title, and Year. In the Validation tab, I used `=UNIQUE(DataSheet!A4:A)` to get the drop-down menu items list for the Reporting Tab.

[Reporting Tab View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGC6M.png)

```
=IF(B2="All Years", "", " AND LOWER(B) = LOWER('"&B2&"') ")
=IF(A2="All Departments", "", " AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ")


`=QUERY(DataSheet!A3:C, "SELECT * WHERE 1=1"& IF(A2="All Departments", "", " AND LOWER(A) = LOWER('"&A2&"') ") & IF(B2="All Years", "", " AND LOWER(B) = LOWER('"&B2&"') "), 1)`
```

Above is the code that queries the DataSheet table and filters based on what I chosen for the Departments Involved and Years, but whenever I try to filter by Years it doesn't work. I was getting an error of:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:"

I tried using `TO_TEXT()` on the Years data in the DataSheet and in the equation from above but that did not work either. Any advice?

Below is a link to the google sheet I am working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FoesYRCM53R_IKSqym_U3l9q_27Xo7_rJHrb35RMOaQ/edit#gid=1009160987

Comment: By sharing spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). [Tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) are preferred. You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells.

Comment: Thank you for the comment regarding my email address. I appreciate that. I was using a pseudo email when I pasted the link to that table with that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

the formula should be:

```
=QUERY(DataSheet!A3:C, "where 1=1 "& 
 IF(A2="All Departments",, " and lower(A) = '"&LOWER(A2)&"'")& 
 IF(B2="All Years",, " and C = "&B2), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: You are amazing...

I have spent way too long trying to figure this out.